# Best way to configure load balancer before elastic search cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently we have a 3 node cluster running 6.2 version in GCP with no dedicated master nodes. All are identical in terms of configuration (4 vCPU, 15 GB RAM nodes - 7GB set as xmx for ES) and settings. We use org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient to access ES cluster. This setup has been running fine for about 2 months now. This morning we experienced some issues on our app server and on checking the logs, I could see that all operations (index and search) on ES were slow. Application that mainly creates data in the cluster accesses one of the nodes (say N1) and application that mainly searches (we have several instances of this application running on a cluster of 2-16 nodes) accesses another node (say N2). Thread dumps showed many threads waiting to get a connection to ES :

```
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.createHttpClient(RestClientBuilder.java:202)
```

This raised doubts on whether one single node is being overburdened with all connection requests coming in. Hence I changed some of the search nodes to connect to third node (say N3) instead of N2. After this change, the situation improved and accessing data from ES became fast. I am not sure if this was the only reason or whether the load on our application server had reduced drastically by the time I figured this out and made the change. I feel this change would have made quite a difference. Hence I feel setting up a LB to distribute the load will be better.

I have read several posts in this forum as well as on elastic forum about the necessity of load balancer in front of ES cluster and I see different responses in different posts :
a) Some say LB is not necessary
b) Some recommend to setup a LB and include only master nodes
c) Some recommend to setup two LBs - one for writing/indexing documents in ES and include only data nodes in this LB and another for queries and include only client nodes in this LB

What is the recommended way of setting up LB?

Comment: `Some recommend to setup a LB and include only master nodes` => NEVER do that !! The only nodes that a client or LB should be in contact with are data, ingest and coordinating nodes, but never master nodes.

Comment: @Val : Sure, I'll keep this in mind. Currently my cluster consists of 3-4 nodes with no dedicated master nodes. Since all are data, ingest and coordinating nodes, I have setup a LB and included all of these nodes. Is this setup okay?

Comment: Yes, in this case, you have no other choice. I just wanted to stress on the fact that your LBs or client should never point to master-only nodes.

Comment: I agree with Shobhana Sriram, I also have  found different sources that say different things about set or not set up an LB in front of a ES cluster.
@Val are there any drawbacks to set up a LB in front of an ES cluster?

Comment: It always depends on your use case :-) There's no right or wrong. Adding an LB can help you isolate your cluster and prevent clients from connecting to a coordinating node directly. An LB provides more flexibility in how you manage your cluster but it also introduces an additional hop (i.e. increased latency).

Comment: we have only 2 nodes and one of them is a new fresh install, so we have applications that communicate only to the old node through nginx that protects the port 9200 from outside. With this configuration, we think that a load balancer could help the first node to spread the load avoiding too much stress on it. Is this a correct thought, @Val ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't have any coordinating-only nodes, then having an LB in front is a good idea to spread the load.

Comment: thank you very much @Val !!!